# How to use multiple data sources in Grails 1.3.3

Tags: grails, datasource

I want to user two data source in single environment.

```
dataSource {
                dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
                 pooled = true
                driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                username = "root"
                password = "" 
                url = ""
                dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
                properties { 
                        maxActive = 75
                        maxIdle = 10
                        minIdle = 2
                        initialSize = 2
                        maxWait = 30000
                        validationQuery="select 1"
                        testOnBorrow=true
                        testWhileIdle=true
                        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=60000
                    } 
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Grails 2.0 multiple data source support is provided by the [Datasources plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/datasources).

Comment: but i am using grails 1.3.3 is any possible solution \

Comment: Yes, you can use multiple data sources if you use that plugin. It works for Grails versions 1.3.x.